# IPtables SNAT eats packets

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I am trying to translate outgoing UDP packets with a source port of X to a source port of Y.

I have done this using the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1 -p udp --sport X -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.1:Y
```

The counters for this rule increase when packets with a source port of X are generated, but completely vanish after that. I cannot find them in the counters of any other chain or table, and cannot see them on any interface using tcpdump.

**If I remove that rule**, then the packets are received fine with the source port of X. But as soon as I put the rule back, the packets vanish.

I am using iptables version v1.2.11 running on Voyage Linux. I am unable to easily update as this will need to be done on a few hundred remote devices.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: iptables config added below, rules related to specific applications that can't affect this have been removed.

```
# Clear any existing rules 
iptables -v -t filter   -F
iptables -v -t nat      -F
iptables -v -t mangle   -F

iptables -v -t filter   -X
iptables -v -t nat      -X
iptables -v -t mangle   -X

# Policies
iptables -t mangle      -P PREROUTING   ACCEPT
iptables -t nat         -P PREROUTING   ACCEPT
iptables -t filter      -P INPUT        DROP
iptables -t filter      -P OUTPUT       ACCEPT
iptables -t filter      -P FORWARD      DROP

# Allow established connections.
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT  
iptables -t filter      -A FORWARD      -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter      -A FORWARD      -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter      -A OUTPUT       -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t filter      -A OUTPUT       -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Allow localhost to talk to itself.
iptables -t filter  -A INPUT      -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Drop stealth scan. 
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -p tcp -s 0/0 -d 0/0 --tcp-flags ALL NONE -j DROP                      
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -p tcp -s 0/0 -d 0/0 --tcp-flags ALL ALL -j DROP                       
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,FIN SYN,FIN -j DROP
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j DROP
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j DROP 
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,FIN FIN -j DROP
iptables -t filter      -A INPUT      -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j DROP

# Allow forwarding from LAN to WAN.
iptables -t filter      -A FORWARD      -i lanif -o wanif -j ACCEPT

# The NAT, strict with fixed IP address - might be different with a DHCP assigned WAN_IP
iptables -t nat         -A POSTROUTING  -o wanif -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP
iptables -t nat         -A POSTROUTING  -m mark --mark 11 -j ACCEPT

# Change source port X to Y - why does this not work???
iptables -t nat     -A POSTROUTING  -s lanif -p udp --sport X -j SNAT --to-source wanif:Y
```

Comment: Can you post whole `iptables -L` output? it looks like something else is blocking it. The rule itself is correct.

Comment: There are quite a lot of rules in iptables, most not related to this, but I can post them if it will help. However, looking at the iptables flowchart, isn't nat/POSTROUTING the last table/chain to process a packet destined for another host?

Comment: I've updated the questions with iptables rules.

Comment: @DanielGibbs Did you find a solution? I have same issue when part of my UDP packets eats and part received and I can't understand why on iptables 1.4.17

Answer (score 4):

> What am I doing wrong?

Probably nothing. It's the way packets traverse Netfilter.

Check this diagram as a reference:

[image]
(Source: [Iptables Tutorial 1.2.1](https://www.frozentux.net/iptables-tutorial/chunkyhtml/index.html) by Oskar Andreasson, 2006)

> I cannot find them in the counters of any other chain or table

`SNAT` is a final Netfilter target, packets will not show up in the same chain afterwards. The `POSTROUTING`-chain in the `nat`-table is the absolute final table a packet can traverse the Netfilter-framework. Tcpdump is attached to a fairly ealier stage, I *think* in `mangle/POSTROUTING`.

> and cannot see them on any interface using tcpdump.
>   That's because tcpdump sees the packet's before they are getting `SNAT`ed.

Is something *actually going wrong*?
It sounds like perfectly normal Netfilter-tcpdump-oddities.

Edit: Your SNAT statement happens in the end. Maybe you need to insert it *before* the `-o wanif -j SNAT --to-source $WAN_IP` statement. Since I have no more details, I can't tell if it's a mistake or intentional.

Comment: Something is definitely going wrong, as I cannot see the packets at the destination. Whereas if I remove the rules, I can see them at the destination. I have also tried moving the rule above the other SNAT rule, but this doesn't make a difference.

Comment: So you really want the source-port to be rewritten? You're sure you don't want the destination port to be rewritten?

Comment: Definitely the source port.

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected to see something like this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1 -p udp --dport X -j SNAT --to-port Y
```

Comment: So would I. Except that `--to-port` is not a valid option. And I want to change the source port, not the destination.

Comment: Oh; 1.2.11 you said; sorry, didn't know that the available options would be that different.  I still think that the --dport is what you need to specify for the translation to be successful.

Comment: Oh. How can I know the destination port if I want the packet to continue to its original destination?

Comment: `--to-port` would be DNAT. DNAT happens in the `nat`-table and in the `PREROUTING`-chain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a service that already listens on that port. `iptables`'s SNAT, when doing the translation will try to keep the same port as the one in the original packet. If this port is not available, it will use another one.

I had this problem trying to SNAT a DNS server's replies. This resulted in the replies being sent from port 1 as the DNS server was already making use of port 53.

The solution was to have the dns server listen on a different port, REDIRECT the incoming traffic from destination port 53 to destination port X and then SNAT also rewriting the port from X to 53.